# How do I stop running Vim macro

Tags: vim, macros

I recorded a macro to a register and started it with too many repetitions. It takes way to much time to complete each macro.

How do I cancel/stop Vim executing macro? Is there a way by doing it without killing editor process?

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Recorded macro to register 1
2. I run it 1000 times: `1000@1`
3. Now waiting about 6 seconds to complete each macro.

Comment: You are supposed to record macros in registers a to z. Registers 1 to 9 are reserved for yanking and deleting and updated each time you do a yank or delete, that's a probable cause for the slowness that you experience.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will switch to letters. On the note of performance I had to do following commands to make it run fast:
syntax off
set undolevels=0

Answer (score 39, accepted):

<kbd>C-c</kbd> works

Also, you can let it break on error. (which, I think, is the default). I sometimes temporarily do

```
 :se nowrapscan
```

to avoid "infinitely" looping over my buffer

---

Also, to speed up macro execution, make it silent:

```
:silent! norm 1000@q
```

Comment: Ctrl-C didn't work on Vim 7.4 for Windows.  I've upgraded to Vim 8.0 and it works there.

Comment: @mwardm Vim (used to) has "Windows mode" default config (I hate it). On Windows, ^C and ^V got mapped to... copy/paste. I think ^Q replaced ^C but I'm not sure. I usually drop any `behave mswin` and related cruft from the vimrc

Comment: @sehe  I think I'd tried ctrl-Q for some reason but unfortunately I already have that as my systemwide hotkey for SlickRun :-)   As you implied, it could well be that the upgrade has resulted in a change to my config that has allowed things to work.