# How to stop an execution of a VIM macro in Idea Vim

Tags: vim, macros, pycharm, ideavim

I have the following problem: while experimenting with `vim` macros in Pycharm (I'm using Idea Vim plugin) - I typed a simple macro and make an editor to run it 100 times. The execution is extremely slow and I couldn't stop it using any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750344/how-do-i-stop-running-vim-macro) pieces of advice. Has anyone had a similar problem and knows how to stop the execution of this macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible in the current IdeaVim 0.50. Feel free to file an issue in the [IdeaVim issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM).